# This site can't be reached took too long time - Laravel

Tags: laravel, apache, server, cpanel, whm

I have a domain. From last night, it's showing "This site can't be reached" took too long time.

I tried logging into domainName.com/cpanel and domainName.com/WHM both links are not working since last night.

Note:`"ping myServerIPAddress"  showing ping time rate average 190 ms`

what can be the reason?

I am using Laravel 5.8

Comment: does `ping domainName.com` show the same ping time and the correct IP? If not then maybe the DNS entry that resolves to the server IP was changed

Answer (score 0):

This is not with your laravel application. Connect with your hosting provider they are only responsible for this. In most cases, this occurs with shared hosting.